# Java IO Copying File

Tags: java, java-io

I've been trying to get a file in java from a internal to a external location. The file is copying but its not transferring the bytes. The file is originally 98 bytes and when transferred then set to 0. If you could tell me what im doing wrong or help me in any sort of way that would be great.

```
    private static void copyFile(String internal, File external) {
    InputStream stream = FileManager.class.getResourceAsStream(internal);
    if(stream == null) {
        System.err.println("Error: File not found when trying to copy at location " + internal);
    }
    OutputStream resStreamOut = null;
    int readBytes;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    try {
        resStreamOut = new FileOutputStream(external);
        while((readBytes = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            resStreamOut.write(buffer, 0 , readBytes);
        }

    } catch(IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {
        try {
        stream.close();
        resStreamOut.close();
        } catch(IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }

}
```

**Edit:**

Getting null pointer:

```
4.4.0 Error: File not found when trying to copy at location /res/shaders/basicFragment.fs
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
com.thinmatrix.konilax.handlers.FileManager.copyFile(FileManager.java:80) at
com.thinmatrix.konilax.handlers.FileManager.update(FileManager.java:56) at
com.thinmatrix.konilax.MainComponent.<init>(MainComponent.java:22) at
com.thinmatrix.konilax.MainComponent.main(MainComponent.java:115)
```

Comment: This should work. Are you sure you have the right input? And that you're not clobbering the output afterwards? I would trace 'readBytes' each time around the loop to make sure you're actually getting here.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the input using `FileManager` correctly?

Comment: Im almost possitive im using FileManager correctly havent used java's io for awhile here's the whole class though if you wanna check. http://pastebin.com/V0QYv1u2

Comment: @user3051391 You have a trivial logic bug. See comments and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only read the file if your code manages to open it (note the else statement when testing if your stream is null):

```
private static void copyFile(String internal, File external) {
    InputStream stream = FileManager.class.getResourceAsStream(internal);
    if(stream == null) {
        System.err.println("Error: File not found when trying to copy at location " + internal);
    } else {
        OutputStream resStreamOut = null;
        int readBytes;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        try {
            resStreamOut = new FileOutputStream(external);
            while((readBytes = stream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                resStreamOut.write(buffer, 0 , readBytes);
            }
        } catch(IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } finally {
            try {
                stream.close();
                resStreamOut.close();
            } catch(IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you great answer but now it is not finding the file and no stacktrace is coming out and clue why

Comment: @user3051391 "internal" should be file name (no path) in the same directory as the `FileManager` class (can be exploded or zipped in a JAR), or a path starting with '/' relative to a directory on the classpath.